# Strange behaviour with fromTo in TimelineMax

Tags: javascript, gsap

Using **TimelineMax** for a new project, I am facing a strange behaviour.

```
var tl = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
tl.add('step0')
  .fromTo('#colorize', 2, { color: '#ff0000' }, { color: '#00ff00' }, 'step0')
  .to('#colorize', 0.5, { color: '#f0f0f0' }, '-=0.5')
  .add('step1');

setTimeout(function() { tl.tweenFromTo('step0', 'step1'); }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() { tl.tweenFromTo('step0', 'step1'); }, 4000);
```

I made this little fiddle to explain:
http://jsfiddle.net/avOff/xorkh2rj/

The text should be red at first (initialized in `fromTo`), then tween to green and finally to gray with an overlap of `0.5` seconds.

It works the first time I play the animation. But if I try to play it a second time (I used a `setTimeout` to simulate) with `tweenFromTo` function, the `from` state of my object is not honoured, it does not initialise to red before going green and gray.

If I remove the `to` block of my timeline it works as expected. Did I miss something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: something to do with the `position` parameter on the `.to()` call. if you remove that, it works fine. not sure why you have that in the first place, I mean, wouldn't you want to first completely tween to `green` and then change from `green` to `gray`. rather than when it has just crossed the half-way point between `red` to `green`, you tell it to start becoming `gray`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for you, **[`overwrite`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/TweenMax/)** is the magic :)

Take a look at the snippet below:

```js
var tl = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
tl.add('step0')
  .fromTo('#colorize', 2, { color: '#ff0000' }, { color: '#00ff00', overwrite: 0 }, 'step0')
  .to('#colorize', 0.5, { color: '#f0f0f0', overwrite: 0 }, '-=0.5')
  .add('step1');

TweenMax.delayedCall(1, function () { tl.tweenFromTo('step0', 'step1'); });
TweenMax.delayedCall(4, function () { tl.tweenFromTo('step0', 'step1'); });
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<p id="colorize">Test color paragraph</p>
```

From the documentation:

> overwrite : String (or integer) - Controls how (and if) other tweens of the same target are overwritten. There are several modes to choose from, but "auto" is the default ...

Read more about it on the **[here](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/TweenMax/)**.

**Update:**

Having said that though, if I was tweening color values, I would **not** want to overlap tweens onto one another (i.e. your `'-=0.5'` position parameter is basically responsible for overlapping its `.to()` tween to the previous `.fromTo()` tween) and I would just let them animate one after another.

Here is an example snippet of that:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('colorize');
var tl = new TimelineMax({ paused: true });
tl.set('#colorize', { backgroundColor: '#cc0' });
tl.to(element, 2, { backgroundColor: '#0cc' });
tl.to(element, 0.5, { backgroundColor: '#ccc' });
TweenMax.delayedCall(1, function () { tl.tweenFromTo(0, tl.totalDuration()); });
TweenMax.delayedCall(4, function () { tl.tweenFromTo(0, tl.totalDuration()); });
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<p id="colorize">Test color paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  overwrite was the answer ! :) Color tweening was just for example